# Dynamically Creating Grid in Angular Component issues with onClick firing on rendering

Tags: angular, typescript, devexpress

I am making a reusable component of the devExpress grid in Angular.
The following code is the reusable component (in the making) and the parent component that uses it.

Issues (So far)

1. The columns and buttons are added dynamically using ngFor. The [onClick] event for the buttons is happening when the row renders, what am I doing wrong or how can I stop this?
2. Can adding attributes become optional, for example on the column I only need to add the attribute 'type' if it is a button row. In angular make it null like [type]="value ? '' : null" but that doesn’t seem to work.

```
parent component html
<core-table-dev-express [dataSource$]="dataSource$" [columns]="columns2" [enableBatchEdit]="true"></core-table-dev-express>
```

```
parent component ts
   //data from server 
   public dataSource$: Observable<Container[]>;
   
   //columns for grid
   public columns2: dxColumn[] = [
        { caption: 'Title', dataField: 'title' },
        { caption: 'Id', dataField: 'id', dataType: 'number' },
        {
            type: "buttons", 
            caption: 'Actions',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Foo',
                parentClassObject: this.alertMe
            },
            {
                text: 'Bar',
                parentClassObject: this.alertMe
            }]
        }
    ]
```

```
grid component html

        <dx-data-grid id="gridContainer1"
                      [dataSource]="dataSource$ | async"
                      keyExpr="id"
                      [repaintChangesOnly]="true"
                      [columnHidingEnabled]="true"
                      [columnAutoWidth]="true"
                      [showBorders]="true"
                      [showColumnLines]="true"
                      [showRowLines]="true"
                      [rowAlternationEnabled]="true"
                      [allowColumnReordering]="false"
                      [allowColumnResizing]="false">
            <dxo-load-panel [enabled]="true"></dxo-load-panel>
            <dxo-column-fixing [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-fixing>
            <dxo-column-chooser [enabled]="true" mode="select"></dxo-column-chooser>
            <dxo-state-storing [enabled]="true" type="localStorage" storageKey="storage"></dxo-state-storing>
            <dxo-search-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-search-panel>
            <dxo-filter-row [visible]="true"></dxo-filter-row>
            <dxo-group-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-group-panel>
            <dxo-scrolling rowRenderingMode="virtual"></dxo-scrolling>
            <dxo-paging [pageSize]="gridDefaultPagesize"></dxo-paging>
            <dxo-pager [showPageSizeSelector]="true"
                       [allowedPageSizes]="[15,25,100]"
                       [showInfo]="true"
                       [visible]="true">
            </dxo-pager>

            <dxo-editing *ngIf='enableBatchEdit' mode="batch"
                         [allowUpdating]="true"
                         [allowAdding]="true"
                         [allowDeleting]="true"
                         [selectTextOnEditStart]="true">
            </dxo-editing>

            <dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns"
                        dataField="{{col.dataField}}"
                        caption="{{col.caption}}"
                        dataType="{{col.dataType}}"
                        type="{{col.type}}">     <!-- can type be conditionally set? -->
                    <dxi-button *ngFor="let b of col.buttons"
                                text="{{b.text}}"
                                hint="{{b.hint}}"
                                cssClass="{{b.cssClass}}"
                                icon="{{b.icon}}"
                                [onClick]="click($event,b)"
                                >
                    </dxi-button>
            </dxi-column>

        </dx-data-grid>
```

```
grid component ts

import {
    Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, AfterContentInit,
    EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone, OnInit
} from "@angular/core";
import { dxColumn } from './../interfaces/table.interfaces';
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source';
import ODataStore from 'devextreme/data/odata/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'core-table-dev-express',
    templateUrl: './table-dev-express.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./table-dev-express.component.scss'],
})
export class TableDevExpressComponent {
    // Shared Variables
    public gridDefaultPagesize = 5;

    @Input() dataSource$: Observable<any>;
    @Input() columns: dxColumn[];
    @Input() enableBatchEdit: boolean;
    @Output() parentMethod = new EventEmitter<any>();

    click = function(e,b) {
        this.parentMethod.emit(b.parentClassObject(e)); // need to send back row data
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`type="{{ condition ? expressionIfTrue : expressionIfFalse }}"`

Comment: I thought I tried that but must of messed something up because I got it to work this time.
 Code I used was: type="{{col.buttons ? 'buttons': null}}"

Comment: Better use an empty string instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

I used the template feature and made my own html instead of using the dxi-button.

I also figured out how to call back to the parent methods but not the prettiest code.

Parent object that is passed in:

```
public columns2: dxColumn[] = [
        { caption: 'Title', dataField: 'title' },
        { caption: 'Id', dataField: 'id', dataType: 'number' },
        {
            caption: 'Actions',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Edit',
                cssClass: "btn btn-primary btn-sm",
                clickMethodName: "routerTo",
                parentClassObject: this
            },
            {
                text: 'Clone',
                cssClass: "btn btn-primary btn-sm",
                clickMethodName: "cloneContainer",
                parentClassObject: this
            }]
        }
    ]
```

Html of shared component

```
     <dxi-column *ngFor="let col of columns"
                            dataField="{{col.dataField}}"
                            caption="{{col.caption}}"
                            dataType="{{col.dataType}}"
                            type="{{col.buttons ? 'buttons': null}}">
    
                    <dxi-button template="rowButtons">
                        <div class="btn-group" *dxTemplate="let data of 'rowButtons'">
                            <div *ngFor="let b of col.buttons">
                                <button class="{{b.cssClass}}" (click)="click(data,b)">{{b.text}}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </dxi-button>
                </dxi-column>
```

typescript code of shared component

```
click = function (row, button) {
       this.parentMethod.emit(button.parentClassObject[button.clickMethodName](row.data))
}
```